# XSSFWorkbook.getSheet() returns null

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am at the end of my wits.  I am using XSSFWorkbook.getSheet(name) - but it returns null, and cannot figure out why.  May be someone has run into it and has found solution.

```
    File file = new File(EXCEL_URL_REDIRECT_LIST_FILE_PATH);

    try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) {
        String excelSheetName = "Sheet 1";
        int numSheets = wb.getNumberOfSheets();
        System.out.println("num sheets: " + numSheets);
        System.out.println(wb.getSheetName(0));

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet(excelSheetName);
        .
        .
        .
     } catch (IOException e) {
     }
```

The console shows:

```
 num sheets: 1
 Sheet 1
```

But the wb.getSheet(excelSheetName) returns null.

What can be possible reasons?

Thanks.

Comment: can you include the code where you declared your Workbook `wb` instance?

Comment: That library IMO is really really bad coding all in all. I had that specific problem too and I just added another method that iterated over the sheets and checked for the right name. Started writing my own libraries for the new standard (xlsx etc), because it is so much faster and far far easier on the RAM etc. Plus I also have a COM connection for direct interop which fits into the exact same interfaces for the workbooks and worksheets.

Comment: Updated the code fragment that shows how wb instance is declared.

Comment: `catch (IOException e)` - I hope that you are printing out this stacktrace.

Comment: @SP i have updated my answer, try it out and check if it works for you

Comment: Please see my response to your updated answer below.

Comment: @Scary Wombat: the stack trace points to next Java code line (not shown above) that tries to get the number of rows on the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `Sheet` instead of `XSSFSheet` cause it worked for me:

```
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(excelSheetName);
```

**Edit**

Also update your declaration for workbook like this:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Comment: Did your code fail when using `XSSFSheet ` ?

Comment: Yes it did, only by using `Sheet` worked for me

Comment: @Donato Amasa:  I modified the code to use Workbook and Sheet classes of org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel pacage.  But the  "sheet" is still null :(

Comment: @Donato Amasa: Just verified that the file is .xlsx format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, resolved the issue.

Cause: sheer dumbness on my part.
Excuse: it is late on long Thursday.

I was trying to search for sheet "Sheet 1" instead of Sheet 1 (without the enclosing double quotes).  The console log showed it when I tried to print it out during debugging; but it took an hour for the light to go on in the brain.

I'm all good now.

MANY and BIG thank you to all who chipped in to provide me help. Love you all.

Comment: we all go through stuff like that man, I'm glad all things are good now cheers!